# Extract all the list elements that are greater than 'm' and less than 'n'

Tags: python

Here is a code for finding all the list elements that are greater than `m` and less than `n`.

Note: `m` and `n` are integer values provided as input

Sample input:

```
[ 1, 5, 9, 12, 15, 7, 12, 9 ] (array)

6 (m)

12 (n)
```

Sample output:

```
[ 9 7 9 ]
```

Here is my code:

```
import ast 

input_list=ast.literal_eval(input())

m=int(input())

n=int(input())

import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array(input_list)

final_array =array_1[array_1>m array_1<n]

print(final_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

If **numpy** is mandatory then you can do this:

```
import ast 
import numpy as np

input_list=ast.literal_eval(input())

m=int(input())

n=int(input())


array_1 = np.array(input_list)

final_array =array_1[(array_1>m)&(array_1<n)]

print(final_array)
```

Comment: but sir I am doing the numpy online class. so please tell me on that

Comment: @TejasJadhao Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use **&** operator

```
import numpy as np
import ast
input_list=ast.literal_eval(input())
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
array_1 = np.array(input_list)
final_array  = array_1[(array_1 > m) & (array_1 < n)]
print(final_array)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/source.py3", line 9, in <module>
    final_array =array_1[array_1>m&array_1<n]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Try my complete code. You missed the paranthesis.. :)

Comment: @TejasJadhao final_array  = array_1[(array_1 > m) & (array_1 < n)]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this just seems like I'm doing your homework for you, but whatever, try this:

```py
import ast 

input_list= ast.literal_eval(input())
m=int(input())
n=int(input())

output_list = [x for x in input_list if m<x<n]
print(output_list)
```

It uses a list iteration to check each item for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Know that you can index arrays with other arrays.

```py
x = np.arange(50) * 2
indexing_array = np.array([3, 5, 9])
print(x[indexing_array])
```

Step 2: Know that you can index arrays with boolean arrays, and that you can create boolean arrays by specifying conditions with an array as one of the arguments.

```py
x = np.arange(50)
# A boolean array
print(x > 5)
# Index x with a boolean array
print(x[x > 5])
```

Step 3: Create conditions such that the boolean array indexes exactly what you want from the original array.

```py
x = np.arange(50)
m, n = 5, 20
print(x[(m < x) & (x < n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast 

input_list=ast.literal_eval(input())
m=int(input())
n=int(input())

import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array(input_list)
final_array =array_1[array_1>m array_1<n]
print(final_array)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input())
b=int(n/2)
a=np.array([[0,1], [1,0]])
m=np.tile(a,(b,b))
print(m)
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions with existing answers (this question is nearly a year and a half old). Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon the existing answers. See [answer].